# Generic typed borrowed value does not live long enough in match

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, ownership

I have this function for quick SQL queries those only expect one value from the DB. I import the postgres 0.19.3 library.

```
fn psql_query<'a, T>(db: &str, query: &str) -> Result<T, postgres::Error>
where
    T: postgres::types::FromSql<'a>,
{
    let client = Client::connect(&format!("host=localhost user=postgres password={} dbname={}", get_password(), db), NoTls);
    match client {
        Ok(mut client) => {
            match client.query_one(query, &[]) {
                Ok(row) => Ok(row.get(0)),
                Err(e) => Err(e)
            }
        }
        Err(e) => Err(e)
    }
}
```

Purpose: connect to DB, return Err() if unsuccessful; then execute query, then return Ok(value) or Err() if something went wrong. The caller can be sure to either get the requested value or the error why it went wrong. Originally I had this very same function with return type `Result<String, Error>` and it worked! Then I realized that maybe I need to query other data types from the DB and thought to utilize generic types instead of implementing separate functions. When I modified the function to use generic types, I started getting the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `row` does not live long enough
   --> src/hc.rs:108:31
    |
100 | fn psql_query<'a, T>(db: &str, query: &str) -> Result<T, postgres::Error>
    |               -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
108 |                 Ok(row) => Ok(row.get(0)),
    |                               ^^^^^^^^^^- `row` dropped here while still borrowed
    |                               |
    |                               borrowed value does not live long enough
    |                               argument requires that `row` is borrowed for `'a`
```

So... why does `row` need to survive any longer? I mean, I just want the return value from `get()` packed into `Ok()`. Since this value will be owned and returned, `row` and `client` can be dropped. Even the carets show that `row` would be dropped after `get(0)` is evaluated, when I don't need it anymore. If `get()` would return a slice or reference that ties the return value to `row`, I would understand, but I don't think this is the case. Why it worked when it was String-only? How can I fix this?
(The `postgres::types::FromSql<'a>` and the `'a` lifetime was required by [`Row.get()`](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/row/struct.Row.html#method.get).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `get()` would return a slice or reference that ties the return value to `row`, I would understand, but I don't think this is the case.

That *can* be the case; the returned type from `get()` must implement [`FromSql<'a>`](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/types/trait.FromSql.html) where `'a` is the lifetime of the `Row`. However, the exact type of value returned is `T`.

The compiler is complaining because the `'a` specified by the caller must be longer than the lifetime of the row.  Your code is effectively saying that the row must live for at least as long as the caller-supplied lifetime, which is impossible.

The most straightforward way to fix this is to say that `T` must implement `FromSql<'a>` *for any possible lifetime `'a`* which you can do with a [higher-rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) (`for`):

```
fn psql_query<T>(db: &str, query: &str) -> Result<T, postgres::Error>
    where T: for <'a> postgres::types::FromSql<'a>
{
    ...
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=beab4afe876e17b28e9a465088c35846))

Comment: Thanks! Every time I think I finally understand lifetimes, I run into another gotcha!